# How to use SMOTE for sequential data

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am training LSTM RNN on sequential data.

I have imbalanced dataset of ~2000 classes.
I would like to use the combination of oversampling/undersampling.

I downsampled more represented classes and wanted to use python implementation of SMOTE to oversample minority classes. However, with RNN, my input is a list of vectors, not a single vector. I tried to use basic example of SMOTE for the task, generating error:

**ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.**

Is there any way to use SMOTE in this way? This is my current code:

```
all_vector_inputs = [vector_pair[0] for vector_pair in all_user_vectors]
all_vector_targets = [vector_pair[1] for vector_pair in all_user_vectors]

inputs_res, targets_res = SMOTE(kind='svm').fit_sample(
    all_vector_inputs, 
    all_vector_targets
)
```

Any SMOTE substitution suggestions in Python welcome as well.

Comment: This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.02514.pdf) might be discussing part of the solution to your problem.